# PHP create object from class with public arrays

Tags: php, object

I have a class for configuration on my script and I implement the config. I then want to use the options as an object reference like the following, but not sure how to get it all the way to the final object field and also how to make it recognize sub arrays too

```
class Configuration {
    public $cookies = array(
        "cookie_prefix"  =>  "site_",
        "site_settings"  =>  array(
                "domain" => "somesite.com",
                "https_only" => TRUE
        ),
        "another_item"   => "and some data too"
    );
}

$config = new Configuration();
echo $config->cookies->cookie_prefix;
echo $config->cookies->site_settings->domain;
```

Right now it works if I do the following

```
echo $config->cookies['cookie_prefix'];
echo $config->cookies['site_settings']['domain'];
```

But I want it to be an object all the way down. Can't wrap my brain around this one for some reason?

I know this is easily done - I am just missing the way how...

Comment: I see no gain in using it as an object over array?

Comment: makes it a lot easier to use for the end user if they can keep everything object related and they're used to a different language is honestly the main reason. The readability of it is another big one - both for myself and our clients. My wife, who knows 0 coding, saw the two versions and said "wow I can actually understand what this one is doing!" to the object version.

Comment: That makes sense if you wanted to make it work like a pure OOP module.

Answer (score 0):

I just passed the items in the `__construct` as json and its working the way I wanted now, duh.

```
public $cookies = array(
    "cookie_prefix"  =>  "site_",
    "site_settings"  =>  array(
            "domain" => "somesite.com",
            "https_only" => TRUE
    ),
    "another_item"   => "and some data too"
);
public function __construct() {
    $this->cookies = json_decode(json_encode($this->cookies));
}
```